# untracked working tree files in git

Tags: git

Every once in a while while I'm developing, I start to accumulate "untracked working tree files" and all I'm doing is `git pull` most of the time. Still, every once in a while I can't do a pull because of the aforementioned "untracked working tree files". Sometimes I do a `git clean` just so I can pull or checkout. What are untracked working tree files? Why am I accumulating them when I'm just doing pulls? Most importantly, why are untracked files preventing me from doing anything? (git warns me that they will be overwritten, but I don't care most of the time. I'm not sure when I would care, so I don';t quite get why git is set to prevent me from doing things when they might be overwritten...)

Answer (score 3):

They are files in your working directory that are not tracked by git.

If you don't wan't them in your repository, and you want git to ignore them, add them to your `.gitignore` file.